# FileUploader.js(Dojo Widget) is not working in mobile but working fine in MobileFirst Console

Tags: file-upload, dojo, ibm-mobilefirst, dojox.mobile

Hi I have tried Integrating **FileUploader.js** **(DOJO WIDGET)** to my sample project in order to Attach and Upload the file contents from local memory

Get the file from sdcard/internal memory and i want show that file in mobile device

- Worked fine in **IBM MobileFirst console**( I was able to upload the file with out any problem
- > **When tested in mobile it's not working.**
- This is where the location of FileUploader.js is in my Project Explorer:

> /dojoLib/toolkit/dojo/dojox/form/FileUploader.js

Please suggest.

```
JS code
```

```js
require(['dojox/form/Uploader', 'dojox/form/uploader/plugins/Flash'], function(Uploader){
  myUploader = new dojox.form.Uploader();
});

function dojoInit() {
 require([ "dojo/ready", "dojo/parser", "dojox/mobile", "dojo/dom", "dijit/registry", "dojox/mobile/ScrollableView", "dojo/data/ItemFileReadStore", "dojo/data/ItemFileWriteStore", "dojox/mobile/SearchBox", "dojox/form/Uploader"], function(ready) {
  ready(function() {
  });
 });
}
```

```
[html code--][1]
```

```html
<div data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.ScrollableView" id="view0" data-dojo-props="selected:true">
      
  <form method="post" action="UploadFile.php" id="myForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
      <input name="uploadedfile" multiple="true" type="file" data-dojo-type="dojox.form.Uploader" label="Select Some Files" id="uploader" />
      <input type="submit" label="Submit" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.Button" />
  </form>

   </div>
```

[Android in in app/res/xml/config.xml already have plugin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oN1HS.png)

[Android in app/AndroidManifest.xml already have plugin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sLyCd.png)

Comment: Yes my apologies for that, my **IBM MobileFirst version : 7.0.0** , **Dojo Version : 1.10.3**

Answer (score 0):

Suggestions:

- mention the MobileFirst version you are working with
- provide actual code

Here's why it is failing for you... When you test in a desktop browser, you are not in a mobile app. You are in a desktop browser. In a desktop browser in your PC you have access to the local filesystem and that's why the widget worked for you.

But when you are in a *mobile device*, you **do not** have access to the file system. You must request this access. To do so, you must use the Cordova FileSystem API. Please refer to that and implement accordingly based on their examples: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/cordova/file/file.html

Comment: what ever the plugins you have said about are existing already for all the environments.

Comment: i  added code and snap-shots  find and help me please

Comment: Dojo is just the front. You still need to implement the Cordova APIs for this to work

Comment: in log file coming like this                                                                                        "[INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "'webkitMovementX' is deprecated. Please use 'movementX' instead.", source:  (0)"